# Можно ли получить цифровой отпечаток сертификата в приложение?

Tags: android

Можно ли получить цифровой отпечаток сертификата из play console в своём приложение на java?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно что бы у любого человека который скачает приложение из play market при открытие приложения брался этот цифровой отпечаток и отправлялся ко мне на сервер. Есть ли какие то библиотеки позволяющие получить сам отпечаток сертификата и будет ли безопасно такое действие с моей стороны в случае декомпеляции моего приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить. Например так:

```
@SuppressLint("PackageManagerGetSignatures")
fun getCertificateFingerprints(packageName: String = context.packageName): List<String?>? {
    try {
        val info = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES
            )
        } else {
            packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                packageName,
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
            )
        }

        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            info.signingInfo.apkContentsSigners
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            info.signatures
        }
            .map {
                MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                    .apply { update(it.toByteArray()) }
                    .digest()
                    .toBase64()
            }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
        return null
    }
}

private fun ByteArray.toBase64() = String(Base64.encode(this, 0))
```

Опасности никакой нет - вы получите только отпечаток ключа, не сам ключ. Полученные значения в целом публичные и не страшно их показывать.

Comment: Ранее я написал что хочу отправлять этот отпечаток на свой сервер, возникает такой вопрос, если злоумышленник который декомпелирует или просто запустит моё приложение подсоединив реальное устройство и запустит приложение при открытой андроид студио, сможет он увидеть сам отпечаток в открытом виде который отправляется на мой сервер или нет? По факту таким образом я хочу сделать аутентификацию своего приложения, сравнивая отпечаток который хранится на сервере и который отправляется с приложения.

Comment: Чтобы получить отпечаток любого приложения достаточно иметь APK файл. Тут даже девайс не очень нужен, можно на эмуляторе через маркет качнуть и парой команд в консоли отпечаток получить. Нет смысла пытаться его защищать.

Comment: Я конечно понимаю что вопрос уже другой не относящийся к этому, Подскажите можно как то провести аутентификацию своего приложения на стороне сервера. По простому если пользователь открыл именно моё приложение то он имеет право на использование моего rest api а вот если пользователь открыл скомпрометированное приложение которое пытается подключится к моему api то доступ к api будет закрыт

Comment: @EvaEvakuator, может вам вот тут что поможет? https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: @EvaEvakuator, в общем случае - это невозможно. Можно всячески усложнять использование вашего API, но при желании всегда можно повторить то, что делает ваше приложение, т.к. приложение доступно всем.

Comment: Можно ли вообще что то из приложения отправить пост запросом таким образом что бы данные которые отправляются не читались в логах а ещё лучше вообще ни как не читались, при этом сами отправляемые данные не хранить в приложение?

Comment: Это невозможно. Сетевые запросы можно легко перехватить и прочитать. Даже если вы данные секретные лично из рук в руки передадите злоумышленник сможет эти данные лично похитить. Сделать 100% надёжную систему невозможно даже в теории